# Is there a way to enable wireless debugging options on my Samsung galaxy a03 core

Tags: android, debugging, wireless

I use a Samsung galaxy a03 core which runs on android 11 version but I can't find the option to enable wireless debugging

Answer (score 0):

Not all tablets seem to have this option. Did you find the USB debugging button? It should be underneath it, if it is available for your device.